# powershell command line parameter are executed in uppercase?

Tags: powershell, wget, case-sensitive

I would like to use a WGET command line program under Windows in a powershell script.

example :
`wget https://domain-name/file_01.pdf -o wgetlog.txt`

**Step 1 - Executed with cmd.exe**, this command works fine :

- Download the file "file_01.pdf" in the current directory.
- Create a log file named wgetlog.txt in the current directory.

**Step 2 - Executed within a powershell script**, this command doesn't work as expected :

- Download the file "file_01.pdf" in the current directory
- Rename it as wgetlog.txt.

WGET is a program with case sensitive parameters :

- -o means "create a log file with a specified name"
- -O means "save the downloaded file with a specified name"

So, I suspect that the script executed with powershell don't take in charge the "case sensitive" functionality and execute the command line "after an upper case conversion".

Is there a way to apply the command with case sensitive or a workaround to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some inexplicable reason, the Windows PowerShell team decided to make `wget` the [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-aliases) name of the [`Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest).

`Invoke-WebRequest` does not even try to be compatible with wget.

To make sure PowerShell uses the *actual* wget program, use its full name, `wget.exe`

```
wget.exe https://domain-name/file_01.pdf -o wgetlog.txt
```

Comment: Using "wget.exe"  instead "wget" solve the problem. Thanks a lot !

Comment: The reason is probably to expose users to the fact that PowerShell doesn't need a separate executable to retrieve web content.

Comment: @Bill I get that, it's still stupid. You can't use the name of a utility so well-established and then so something that is not compatible *at all*. That breaks a fundamental rule of API design - that you should not do something surprising.

Comment: Also, did you downvote my post because you disagree with my word choice? I thought downvotes were for incorrect answers.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I do disagree that it was a stupid decision. It wasn't arbitrary; PowerShell's designers did the same thing with the `dir` alias, for example.

Comment: I see... with `dir` it's a bit less problematic because this was in the Windows domain all along. It's what one would type into a Windows shell prompt. `wget` on the other hand isn't... Especially if there's an actual wget in the PATH. Overriding that is far from smart.

Comment: We will agree to disagree, then.